# how to add files simultaneously to database

Tags: java, mysql

I have written a Java code that receives messages from sensors continuously. So I need to dump this information from the text file(in which I am writing the received data) to MySQL database. Is this possible to do it simultaneously?

Comment: Your MySQL database has a connection pool which it manages.  MySQL can handle synchronizing incoming queries but you still need to deal with this on the Java side.

Comment: The issue might be opening the file that's permanently written to. Can you do like a rotation on the files you write?

Comment: will you give more details on this Skand?